# How to get access value from jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple checkboxes and trying to get only checked check boxes but while applying jquery i cannot access the value from outside its scope. The reason for this is that i ve to pass ajax request and fail to do anything.

my code html:

```
<div name="state" id="state">
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="offer1" name="offer" value="Monday">Monday
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="offer2" name="offer" value="Tuesday">Tuesday
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="offer3" name="offer" value="Wednesday">Wednesday
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="offer4" name="offer" value="Thursday">Thursday
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" id="offer5" name="offer" value="Friday">Friday
</label>


</div>  
<button name="submit" onclick="continued()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="font-size:18px;">Continue</button>

<script>
function continued(){
    var s=$("#school").val();
    var st=$("#student").val();
    var selected = [];
    var sThisVal;
var v =$('#state input:checkbox').each(function (elem) {
 sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
//alert(sThisVal);
return sThisVal;

});

alert(v[0]);




}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each()` do not have return type. You should use `.map()` function along with `.get()` here:

```
var v = $('#state input:checkbox').map(function(elem) {
  var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
  return sThisVal;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function continued() {
  var selected = [];
  $("#state input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    selected.push(this.value);
  });
  console.log(selected);
  return selected;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="state">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Monday">Monday
</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Tuesday">Tuesday
</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Wednesday">Wednesday
</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Thursday">Thursday
</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" value="Friday">Friday
</label>
</div>
<button onclick="continued()">Continue</button>
```